# Avatar Glow widget in flutter app is not working. How to solve this?

Tags: flutter, floating-action-button, avatar

[image]

I am using avatar glow in floating action button. I am trying to make it glow, when I tapped on it., But this avatar glow widget is not working.. Can anyone give me solution? or what widget should use instead of this widget to glow the floating action button?

Comment: please paste code, not the image of the same

Comment: i am using avatar glow in floating action button.. Is this the problem? when I used it on a container it works.

Comment: how can I make a glow effect on floating action button

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
 floatingActionButton: AvatarGlow(
          glowColor: Colors.blue,
          endRadius: 90.0,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
          repeat: true,
          showTwoGlows: true,
          repeatPauseDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),        
          child: FloatingActionButton(
                 onPressed: (){},
                 tooltip: 'Floating',
                 child: const Icon(Icons.mic),
        ),
```